# Purification for haram meat

Tags: halal-haram

If we touch a meat which is slaughter in proper manner and said bismillah during slaughtering but one who slaughter his aqeedah is corupt or he do major shirk then I know the meat is haram but do we have wash our hand or clothes or whereever we touched place

Comment: That major shirk ,which I forget to write in 3 sentences

Comment: You can edit the question and explain the major shirk.